# Getting squiggles error on for loops inside a @code block on a razor page Blazor

Tags: loops, razor, blazor

Getting squiggles error on for loops inside a @code block on a razor page Blazor
[error in loop inside block code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3ldz.jpg)

```
@code{ 
  string Vh = "0 0 600 200";
  int i = 0; List<string> dis2 = new List<string>();
  string[] dis = { "400", "650", "660", "700", "750", "800", "850", "900", "950", "950", "950" };
  private static System.Timers.Timer aT;
  foreach (var v in dis){}
  private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
}
```

Comment: @code{
    string Vh = "0 0 600 200";
    int i = 0;
    List<string> dis2 = new List<string>();
    string[] dis = { "400", "650", "660", "700", "750", "800", "850", "900", "950", "950", "950" };
    private static System.Timers.Timer aT;
    foreach (var v in dis){}
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

}

Comment: The code block is a class level container. Your loop needs to be inside a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a foreach loop inside a class body. You need to put it inside a method or use it above the @code section, then it will need a @foreach.

```
@foreach (var v in dis)
{
}
@code
{
    string Vh = "0 0 600 200";
    int i = 0;
    List<string> dis2 = new List<string>();
    string[] dis = new[] { "400", "650", "660", "700", "750", "800", "850", "900", "950", "950", "950" };
    private static System.Timers.Timer aT;
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
}
```